# Selecting all messages from individual ips that has 20 or more messages

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all the messages from individual ips that has 20 or more messages, but I'm having trouble selecting it. Here's my query:

```
SELECT messages
FROM currentChat
HAVING count(id) >= 20
GROUP by ip
```

Comment: You need to show sample data and your expected results.  My guess: You are GROUPING on ip, which means only one, and a random one at that, message is being shown for that ip - which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery to get your results

```
SELECT * 
FROM currentChat 
WHERE ip IN (SELECT ip FROM currentChat GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(*) >= 20)
```

Comment: What does (ip in) refer to?

Comment: Kind of like a shortcut to saying (ip = value1 OR ip = value2 OR...etc)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Answer (score 2):

You need a `join` or something similar:

```
SELECT cc.*
FROM currentChat cc JOIN
     (SELECT ip, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM currentChat
      GROUP by ip
      HAVING cnt >= 20
     ) i20
     ON cc.ip = i20.ip;
```